# SurffaceView camera preview: find camera preview size without stretch

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I'm going crazy with a problem with surfaceview and camera preview. My problem is that preview (in portrati mode) is stretched, and i can't understand why (on nexus  7 device).
This is layout contains surfaceview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".pic" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_border"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <!-- android:layout_below="@+id/surfaceview" -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/footer" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

So, footer ImageView contain a footer with some other views (button for take pics, accept ore deny pics and others), and View (initialized programmatically) is a semi transparent view that show user limit of picture (picture taken will be squared).
This is how i initialize Camera object (surfaceChanged method)

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size result = getBestPreviewSize(params, width, height);

    params.setPreviewSize(result.width, result.height);
    params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    params.setJpegQuality(100);
    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    // params.set
    params.setPictureSize(dpWidth, dpWidth);
    // default orientation is in landscape
    params.setRotation(90);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    mCamera.startPreview();
```

and this is how i calculate best preview size:

```
public Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters params, int width,
        int height) {

    Camera.Size result = null;
    for (Camera.Size size : params.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea > resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

supported previews sizes are

```
w: 1920 h: 1080
w: 1280 h: 768
w: 1280 h: 720
w: 1024 h: 768
w: 800 h: 600
w: 800 h: 480
w: 720 h: 480
w: 640 h: 480
w: 352 h: 288
w: 320 h: 240
w: 176 h: 144
```

and chosen one is

```
1024 768
```

images on preview appear thinner and higher than reality.
How could i fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The preview is being scaled to match the size of the SurfaceView.  You need to wrap the SurfaceView with a layout that can be adjusted to maintain the aspect ratio of the camera input.

One example of this is the [AspectFrameLayout](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java) class in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  You can see it used in the activities that show a camera preview (e.g. "Continuous capture" and "Show + capture camera").  Your layout will look something like this:

```
<com.android.grafika.AspectFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/continuousCapture_afl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/continuousCapture_surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</com.android.grafika.AspectFrameLayout>
```

Then you set the size from the camera parameters:

```
    Camera.Size cameraPreviewSize = parms.getPreviewSize();
    AspectFrameLayout layout = (AspectFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.continuousCapture_afl);
    layout.setAspectRatio((double) cameraPreviewSize.width / cameraPreviewSize.height);
```

Comment: Thanks this has got me pointed in the right direction. I have a question though. I manually set both the camera preview size AND the surfaceHolder size to match one particular size (say 768 x 1280) and it was still coming out skewed. I did NOT wrap the cameraPreview class (i.e. a surfaceView) inside a frame layout though. My question is why does it matter if I tried setting both the camera preview and surfaceHolder sizes exactly? Why wouldn't that work too?

Comment: Bear in mind that the camera can only be set to certain sizes, as reported by the `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` call on the camera parameters. If you're not using one of those sizes, the actual size may be different. You can use `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` to see the actual sizes of the surface and the surfaceview; see https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#composition for an example. From that you will be able to see if what you're getting matches what you're asking for, and whether the aspect ratios of both match.

Comment: I didn't explain it well I think. Ill keep at it and if Im still stuck next week I'll post a question. Thanks!

Comment: @fadden can u pls tell i applied same code but still orientation is not perfect

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing the best preview size using this method:

```
public static Camera.Size getBestAspectPreviewSize(int displayOrientation,
                                                   int width,
                                                   int height,
                                                   Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    double targetRatio = (double) width / height;
    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    if (displayOrientation == 90 || displayOrientation == 270) {
        targetRatio = (double) height / width;
    }
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Collections.sort(sizes,
            Collections.reverseOrder(new SizeComparator()));
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio);
        }
        if (minDiff < 0.0d) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return (optimalSize);
}
```